# Two Way Binding between Sibling Components

Tags: angular

I am having an issue where i can't pass data from one component to the next using 2-way binding.

The structure is this

```
<div class="container">
<component-one> "Containers Input Tag" and ngModel </component-one>
<router-outlet>
<component-two></component-two>
<component-three></component-three>
</router-outlet>
</div>
```

Component-One has this `Template`

```
<input class="negligible" [(ngModel)]="model_data">
```

How do i get `model-data` into all other components i need them to be?

**This is a `.ts` file with what i am trying to implement**

I would like to use the string generated from the

`component-one`

```
export class ComponentOne implements OnInit {

model_data = 'model_string';
items: Observable<any[]>;
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {


}

ngOnInit(): void {
}

update() {
this.dataService.updateData(this.model_data);
}
}
```

**The other Components are as follows**

```
export class ComponentTwo implements OnInit {


model_data = model_string;
title = 'First';
items: Observable<any[]>;
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, private titleService: Title, private meta: Meta, private dataService: DataService) {
this.items = db.list(this.model_data, ref => ref.limitToLast(100)).valueChanges().pipe(map(values =>     values.reverse()));

}

ngOnInit(){
this.titleService.setTitle(this.title);
this.meta.addTag({name: 'Negligible', content: 'Negligible'});
}

subscribeToData() {
this.dataService.dataObservable$.subscribe((data) => (this.model_data = data));
}
```

**The Service file**

```
export class DataService {

model_data= model_string;
constructor() {

}

public subject = new Subject<any>();
dataObservable$ = this.subject.asObservable();

updateData(data: any) {
this.subject.next(data);
}

}
```

Comment: Two way binding is something you do between an input in your template and a variable in the accompanying typescript file. There's no such thing as two way binding between different components. Either you use a service (observable service like in Nehal's answer, or an eventbus), or you emit an event to the parent with an output to have the parent pass it to the other child with an input. If you create a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) I'd be happy to help out, but Nehal's answer is good advice.

Comment: There is no [mre] in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inter child data communication, it's better to use `subject` or `behavior`, that allows the publish/subscribe mechanism.

In a service file, define a subject:

```
SomeServie {
  private dataSource = new Subject<any>();
  dataObservable$ = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  updateData(data: any) {
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }

}
```

From your component-one.ts, publish the event to dataSource:

```
<input class="negligible" [(ngModel)]="model_data" (blur)="update()">

update() {
  this.someService.updateData(this.model_data);
}
```

In component-two and component-three, subscribe to dataObservable:

```
subscribeToData() {
   this.someService.dataObservable$.subscribe((data) => {
     // data is the model_data passed from component-one   
   });
}
```

Whenever, component-one publishes data, this observable will capture the emitted value every time.

Don't forget to declare the service in each component's constructor.

```
constructor(..., private someService: SomeService) {}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-ukrvfd)

Comment: This is not working. The `model_data` never gets updated .

Comment: In your component two, you didn't call `subscribeToData()` inside `ngOnInit()`. How do you expect the component to start the subscription? Also, I don't see any event binding in component one's html, that will trigger `update()` function to emit the latest 'model_data' value

Comment: On your review, these are the only issues ? I have something similar to a search bar, I would like the function to be triggered on a press of `Enter` . How should i do so ?

Comment: <input [(ngModel)]="model_data" (keyup.enter)="update()"

Comment: I am getting an error with `subscribeToData()` don't believe it is possible to place the method inside of `ngOnInit` . I unwrapped the body and everything compiled, but, same issue as before.

Comment: I know the binding is works, but the other components can't access.

Comment: It does work, check the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-ukrvfd)

Comment: That works. I am going to have to read this thoroughly. I have figured two things I did wrong here. `First` I added the service to the `app.module` **singletons should not be added** . `Second` I called the `subscrbeToData()` wrong. Is it okay if I `clone` the **stackblitz** ?

Comment: Glad it helped, feel free to clone. Please accept and upvote the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I am having another issue. I am trying to use the `output` of the binding to change the **database route** of **Angular Fire** like this `constructor(private appService: AppService, db: AngularFireDatabase, private titleService: Title, private meta: Meta) {
  this.items = db.list(this.data,  ref => ref.limitToLast(100)).valueChanges().pipe(map(values => values.reverse()));
  }` . The binding works well when `Interpolated`, but it never updates for the `Angular Route`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246296/discussion-between-nova-nova-and-nehal).

Comment: That is not in the scope of your question. I have resolved the question as it was asked. I would appreciate if you can mark it as accepted. You can open a new question for your Angular Fire issue.