# Sending an array to a different component with mat-sidenav

Tags: angular, mat-sidenav

I've been searching for a solution but havent found one.

I have a component which displays a list of fetched data and every row has a checkbox. Also im using mat-sidenav to display 2 sidenavs and router-outlet to display main-content. The right sidebar should display properties of selected (by checking) data. How do i get access to the data if they aren't parent-child components? Every selected object goes to the array which i would like to send into my sidebar-component. I was thinking about new service but im not really sure how should it look.

Comment: A service is the way to go here. You implement some `Observable` that is being updated by the selected checkboxes while your sidenav component can subscribe to it and be notified of any changes.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72912159/5556177) to create a pub/sub communication between components.

Comment: So i've created a new service(x) which is using another service to get the users data since it is needed for my checkbox logic implementation which i also hold in a 'x' service and i use the methods in my components template.  Now im trying to create an observable like @AldinBradaric said? Is it a good way?

Comment: @rbrtj You could update your question with the new code if you want more feedback.

Comment: Well, with Your help i figured it out, thanks :)