# how to pass input data with ng content

Tags: angular

How can I pass input data from child component to the child component using ng content

Example

```
parent component 

<parent-component>
  <child-component1>


  </child-component1>

</parent-component>
```

```
child component 1

<div>
  <ng-content [input_value]="value"></ng-content>
</div>
```

The question does it work if I use child component 1 in parent component
such as

```
<child-component1>

  <the-other-component [inputValue] ="value"></the-other-component>
  </child-component1>
```

or maybe there is any other solutions?

Comment: You can share data between components, regardless of their relation, via `subject` or `behaviorSubject`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72912159/5556177) for more info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Way Binding between Sibling Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72911783/two-way-binding-between-sibling-components)