# Angular - How to pass parameter from one component to the other without using snapshot params

Tags: angular

In Angular-14 project, I have two components student-list and student-edit

student-list.component.html:

```
  <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" (click)="editStudentData(row)">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit
  </a>
```

student-list.component.ts:

```
  editMerchantUserData(row: any) {
    console.log(row);
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(StudentEditComponent, Object.assign({}, { class: 'gray modal-lg' }));
  }
```

In student-list.component.ts, **console.log(row)** gives:

```
{id: '053f9532-5d0c-49fc-aa09-e095f3491149', firstName: 'Smith', lastName: 'Jacobs', email: 'sjacobs@gmail.com', …}
```

Then in student-edit without using this.route.snapshot.params['id'], I want this._id = row.id as shown below:

student-edit.component.ts:

```
_id!: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this._id = row.id;
  }
```

How do I achieve this by passing row.id from student-list to student-edit without using snapshot params?

Thanks

Comment: You can share data between components via subject/behaviorSubject, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72912159/5556177)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Way Binding between Sibling Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72911783/two-way-binding-between-sibling-components)