# Update child component in from another component angular

Tags: angular

Can I update component whichis declared two different component? please take a look the photo, there i have two different components and inside the components I have child component selector, can I update my child component in the `component 2` from `component 1`?[image]

I tried to make some service and inside that declare a subject and on a button click do next() and there subscribe for changes but my attempt is failed

Comment: Yes you can, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72912159/5556177)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Way Binding between Sibling Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72911783/two-way-binding-between-sibling-components)